# How to expand the search bar from center to both sides with transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to expand hidden search bar from center of div to both sides of div by clicking on search icon, using css. But it always expand to one side either left or right. I need transition to both sides simultaneously.
I need solution with purely css without javascript or jquery. I tried animations, transitions, positions everything but didn't find any solution.  How I can solve this.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.search-label').on("click",function(e){
      $(".form-groups").addClass("move");
      $("#for-grp").addClass("search-open");
      $("#for-grp").removeClass("box-visible");
       $(".close-label").removeClass("d-block");
    });
});
```

```css
.main
{
  position:relative;
  width: 50%;
  background-color:  aliceblue;
}
.form-groups{
  width: 0%;
  transition: width 1s;
}
.pull-right
{
  float: right;
}
.search-label
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.sibling
{
  clear:  right;
}
#for-grp
{
  width:  90%;
  display: block;
  margin-left:25px;
  height: 20px;
}
.box-visible
{
  visibility:hidden;
}
.move
{
  width:100%;
}
.search-open
{
  border: none !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
.close-label
{
  position:absolute;
  right:0px;
}
.d-block
{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
 

    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        </head>
        <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="form-groups pull-right" style="display:inline" id="search">
                <span class="search-label bg-white">
                    <i class="fa fa-search icon_search"></i>
                </span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="for-grp" class="box-visible">
            </div>
            <span class="close-label d-block"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></span>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: you mean the line will be before and after `x` buttons??

Comment: You are already using jQuery but the solution can't use it ?

Comment: I am using jquery for binding click function. which is okay, I don;t have to use js or jquery for transition @Sandwell

Comment: Just an additional issue, you forgot the closing quotes on the form-groups style  <div class="form-groups pull-right" style="display:inline;" id="search">

Comment: Yes the line will expand before and after X button. Then after I will also move X button to the end @לבני מלכה

Comment: @Sirence, Tried after resolving quotes issue but, its not working

Comment: @BhuvanArora, as I said, it is just an additional issue on top of your problem. But for your problem, it can be solved by using transform for the animation: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Comment: @BhuvanArora, also yor main <div> opens but never closes - again, just an additional issue, nothing to do with the animation but still needs to be fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no style to it but maybe this is what your looking for

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('i.fa-search').on("click",function(e){
      $('.holder').addClass('open');
    });
});
```

```css
.main
{
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color:  aliceblue;
}

input {
  width: 0%;
  display: none;
}

i.fa {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

i.fa-search {
  left: 0;
}

i.fa-close {
  right: 0;
  display: none;
}

.holder {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 0%;
  transition: width 1s;
}

.holder.open {
  width: 50%;
}

.holder.open input {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.holder.open i.fa-close {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        </head>
        <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="holder">
               <input placeholder="Search" type="text">
               <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
               <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
            </div>
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```